# Mock any method signature with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

Hi I have this piece of code that is not very well designed, but I'm not the owner of this code so I can't change it.

```
public interface Car{ // This is a marker interface. }

public class BigCar implements Car{ 
  public boolean isVeryBig(){ 
  return true;}
} 

public class QuiteBigCar implements Car{ 
  public boolean isVeryBig(boolean withHatchBack){ 
  return true;}
}   

public Pickup implements Car{ 
  public boolean isVeryBig(boolean withHatchBack, boolean withRoofRack){ 
  return true;}
}
```

You see the interface only exists to let me know that `BigCar`, `QuiteBigCar` and `Pickup` "is a" Car. Not very clever, but that's what I have to deal with.

Now I have a method that receives a Car as a param and will returned a mocked version of the car. I want the mock to make sure every time `isVeryBig()` is called, it will return false **regardless of the method signature**. The problem is I don't have a common interface for all `isVeryBig()` methods; they all have a different signature.

```
public Car mockMyCar(Car car){

     Car mockedCar = mock(car);

     when(mockedCar.isVeryBig())  <-- This wont work since the method doesn't exist on the interface

    return mockedCar;
}
```

Yes, I could cast Car into their subclass but this is not an option for me as there is too many classes that implement Car, make a instanceOf check on all implementation would make the code very nasty and I don't control new implementations of Car in the future.

Any idea?

Comment: this has nothing to do with mockito. If you access the object through the "car" interface you cannot call any method without downcasting, let alone mock it...

Comment: If I were you I'd create a `CarFixed` interface declaring the method, then an `AbstractCarFixed` with static factory methods to create different "concrete" `Car`s. This way you can at least mock `CarFixed`.

Comment: @TrustNoOne I agree this is a fundamental Java problem. However, there was a way around it using JMock. I could do:   mockedCar.stubs().method("isVeryBig").will(returnValue(false)); So, yes that's a limitation I'm facing now that I'm using Mockito.

Comment: @fge Remeber there is many Car implementations and I don't control them. I'm not the owner of the Car implementation classes. There is no way I can create a factory method myself, since I don't control what kinf of Car implementation will exist in the future.

Comment: `mock(car)` won't compile either. Are you doing something like `mock(car.getClass())` or `spy(car)`?

Comment: @MichałPolitowski maybe the example I gave is not exactly like my code, but my issue is related to the method signature... not the mock itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few options, in order from least-hacky to most-hacky:

- Acknowledge that mocking a Car here makes as little sense as mocking a Serializable, and that you should actually pick an implementation to mock. You won't have the same trouble mocking a concrete BigCar or Pickup, and you can run through a few different implementations in a few test cases.
- Refactor to a common properly-polymorphic interface as TrustNoOne described, rather than using ersatz polymorphism the way you have here. I know you may have your hands tied, but whoever stumbles across this question next might not.
- You can do something similar to what you're describing—matching methods by name instead of signature—by [supplying a default Answer](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock%28java.lang.Class,%20org.mockito.stubbing.Answer%29) when you create the mock:

  ```
  Car car = Mockito.mock(Car.class, new Answer<Object>() {
    @Override public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
      if (invocation.getMethod().getName().equals("isVeryBig")) {
        return false;
      }
      // Delegate to the default answer.
      return Mockito.RETURNS_DEFAULTS.answer(invocation);
    }
  };
  ```

  Bear in mind, though, that your particular situation (of being able to downcast to one of a variety of implementations with different signatures) may require use of the [extraInterfaces](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#extraInterfaces%28java.lang.Class...%29) feature to let Java downcast as needed, which makes this entire thing tricky and fragile. You'd probably be better off using one of the other above solutions instead.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Bowman your answer is very complete. Although, I realize that there is no way around my problem really. I like your last hacky version I will definitely try it.