# Can I create one generic mock for methods with the same name but different method signatures?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

Let's say I have a class, UserDAO(), with multiple methods named findUser(). However, this findUser() method is overloaded multiple times, and a User object is returned in all instances.

For example:

```
public class UserDAO {

    public User findUser(int param1) {
        *do stuff to create a user object*
        return User;
    }

    public User findUser(int param1, long param2) {
        *do stuff to create a user object*
        return User;
    }

    public User findUser(long param2) {
        *do stuff to create a user object*
        return User;
    }
}
```

Let's say that I want this class to return some generic User object when testing other classes. So I want something like:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {

    User mockedUser = mock(User.class);
    UserDAO mockedUserDAO = mock(UserDAO.class);

    when(mockedUserDAO.findUser(*any parameter*)).thenReturn(mockedUser);
}
```

Essentially, I don't want to have to mock every findUser() method individually. Is there any way to do this?

It looks like the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939246/mock-any-method-signature-with-mockito) might provide a hint, but I'm having a hard time understanding the most-hacky solution as I'm pretty novice when it comes to coding.

Comment: "*Essentially, I don't want to have to mock every findUser() method individually.*" - For each test, you should only mock what you need. Do you need all implementations in one test? If so: should all calls really return the same `User`?

Comment: Also: how is this question related to `powermockito`?

Comment: So there are two issues that have led me to this problem:
1. I was told that I would only want to mock objects on the database level.
2. The code base is large enough and interconnected enough such that every new test class would have maybe 150 lines of imports and mocks just to run at a basic level.


I'm trying to create one class that would serve all the basic mock setup you need so that you don't have to repeat these 150 lines for every new JUnit test class for each new file.

Sometimes the user object doesn't matter. In the cases it does, the person can specify behavior when needed

Comment: This question might not be related to powermockito. I've just started using this a week ago. But I'm using mockito and powermockito to mock these classes, and I know they each add some mocking functionality. So maybe Powermockito can enable what I'm trying to do if Mockito doesn't.